# Keep form data when opening and closing extension?

Tags: javascript, forms, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing an extension for Google Chrome, where users fill out a form through this.

**How it works:**

1. User clicks on the extension icon and a popup appears with form;
2. Start filling out the form;
3. Ends filling;
4. Send form;
5. End.

**Problem:**

1. The user clicks on the extension icon and a popup appears with form;
2. Start filling out the form;
3. User clicks on the extension icon inadvertently or out of the popup;
4. Extension closes;
5. User opens again;
6. Data already filled were lost;
7. Extension becomes unfeasible;
8. End.

   I need to know how not to lose this data, but I do not even know how to Google it. Can you help me?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions on Stack Overflow should be in English.

Comment: My mistake! All translated.
Can you help me with it? @GordonLinoff

Comment: You still need to translate the title.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Usually, including a *manifest.json*, some of the background *and* content scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a nutshell, here's how one can do it:

1. On every input change, save it to a persistent storage
2. On popup load, load the saved data
3. On successful completion of the form, clear the saved data

There are different options for persistent storage in Chrome extensions, but the most "native" is the `chrome.storage` API. You can find samples [in the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) and here on SO.

That covers loading and saving the data, but how to catch input change? Well, there's a helpful `oninput` event for form fields.

So the basic idea:

```
var keys = [/* a list of your fields' ids as keys */];

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  chrome.storage.local.get(keys, function(data) {
    /* find the form fields and set their state from data, for example 
       (depends on the field type - maybe not .value) */
    for (let key of keys) {
      let field = document.getElementById(key);
      field.value = data[key];
      field.oninput = saveData;
    }
  });
})

function saveData(e) {
  chrome.storage.local.set({[this.id]: this.value});
}

function clearData() { // To be called when you submit your data
  chrome.storage.local.remove(keys);
}
```

It's a very rough draft; try to get the idea and adapt it from there.